# Azure web app work with azurewebsites but not with domain

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, ssl-certificate

I created a web app with Angular 9 on top of asp.net core using web api, everything is working ok using the myapp.azurewebsites.net but when I access the app using app.mydomain.com I start getting unauthorized calls to my web api methods (using autorize in controller), the autentication is with identity server with a pfx certificate created by azure and bind to the domain... what is wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you are using the Traffic Manager, can you check the Configuration and make sure that Protocol is set to "HTTPS"?

Comment: Both are https...